# Сделать кликабельный label для select

Tags: html, css

Здравствуйте нужна помощь.

На сайте иконка нормально размещена, но она не кликабельна.
Нужно чтобы при нажатии на нее раскрывался список...
Либо как еще можно сделать?

```css
.label-for-rewiew{
    background-image: url(../img/sumo-arrow.png);
    background-position: center center;
    width: 16px;
    height: 16px;
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    right: 20px;
    bottom: 30px;
    margin: auto;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    opacity: 0.8;
}

#selectID{
    position: relative
    appearance: none;
}
```

```html
<label class="label-for-rewiew" for="selectID"></label>
 <select id="selectID" name="rewiew-doctor" class="rewiewForm">
 <option value='' hidden>Выберите врача</option>
   @foreach($doctors as $key => $doctor);
    <option value="{{$key}}">{{$doctor->h1}}</option>
              @endforeach

   </select>
```

Answer (score 0):

Ну, во-первых, label-иконка и не должна быть кликабельна. Это ж не кнопка. 
если хотите чтобы на клик по ней как-то что-то реагировало, нужно написать свой обработчик события на яваскрипте.

Если же задача состоит в том, чтобы присобачить собственную иконку элементу `select` вместо стрелки, то и впихните ее как background-image селекту:

```
select {
  background-image: url(...);
  appearance: none;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: right center;
}
```